# I just try to install Netbeans but there are more probs with JDK

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans

im new at ubuntu and i want to use netbeans. I downloaded netbeans from its web site then I wrote this commands to the line

```
 hakki@hakki-K55VM:~/Downloads$ chmod +x netbeans-7.4-linux.sh

 hakki@hakki-K55VM:~/Downloads$ sudo bash netbeans-7.4-linux.sh

 [sudo] password for hakki:

Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer
JDK 7 is required for installing the NetBeans IDE. Make sure that the JDK is properly installed and run installer again.
You can specify valid JDK location using --javahome installer argument.

To download the JDK, visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
```

After I get above notification I tried to install JDK with these commands

```
 hakki@hakki-K55VM:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
 .... 

 done
```

then I controled jdk installed properly and it returned below lines

```
 hakki@hakki-K55VM:~$ java -version

java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

After I download jdk I tried to install netbeans again but still it returns error and it cant initialize UI. How can I solve this problem?

```
 hakki@hakki-K55VM:~/Downloads$ sudo bash netbeans-7.4-linux.sh

Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
Can`t initialize UI
Running in headless mode

Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
```

Comment: Why do you install a headless JRE with apt-get when you're being instructed to install a JDK to download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads? JRE means: runtime environment (i.e. without all the dev tools of the JDK). And headless means: without UI, although you want to run a graphical application. Follow the instructions, and everything will be easier.

Comment: Actually I just followed some instructions from web. So when I try to install jdk I did not follow instructions carefully

Answer (score 4):

The NetBeans says it needs a JDK (Java Development Kit), but you only installed a JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

> I tried to install JDK with these commands
>
> ```
>    hakki@hakki-K55VM:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
> ```

You installed a JRE, not JDK.

This should be enough

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```